# How to deal with webpack chunk updated on server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

We have a React application with code splitting using React.lazy and Suspend. Every Tuesday we deploy a new version and so our chunks will change too.

The problem we have right now is if our user did not refresh after we deploy, their old `main.js` is still pointing to the old chunk files with old hashes. And it's going to crash when they try to load the old chunk files.

We know that we can prefetch routes when our app is loaded but there are a lot of routes to be prefetched (around 20). This might affect our home page performance because we have a few API calls on home page.

Are there any better ways of dealing with this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: We are talking about the hashes that Webpack generates in the chunks filename? Could you show the relevant parts of your Webpack config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have decided to preload every route in background so our clients do not need to lazy load other chunks at a later point in time.

Answer (score 1):

- [Use the `[hash]` placeholder](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputfilename) in the your Webpack output configuration, e.g. `filename: '[hash]/[name].js'`. This way every compilation will yield a fresh set of filenames.
- Ensure the page that refers to these chunks (be it generated with webpack-html-plugin or something else) is always served fresh, never from cache, via Cache-Control headers or other similar techniques.

This way very stubborn clients (who disregard the cache-control headers) will most probably use their old version of your code, but as soon as they refresh (to get the new HTML page), they'll be guaranteed all of the new JavaScript too, since the URL has changed.

Answer (score 0):

What keeps you from keeping multiple versions on your server? Let's say `v1.commons.js` is currently deployed. Now when you build a new version, `v2.commons.js` gets created, and both files are served by the server. Old clients will still work with the old version, but depending on your caching settings (page expiry time) they will migrate soon to the new version. Then you can remove the old version from your server.